# How many ways are there to arrange $5$ red, $5$ blue, and $5$ green balls in a row so that no two blue balls lie next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Um I know that there are $\large\frac{15!}{5!5!5!}$ combinations but I'm kinda stumped after that.

I tried doing the space thing and I got ${11 \choose 5}^2$ after my answer.

I don't really know what to do.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Hint: *for the purpose of placing the blue balls only*, red and green are equivalent. So when it comes to placing blue balls, you have 5 blue and 10 non-blue balls. Easier now? (Red and green are still distinct for the purposes of placing *them*)

Answer (score 7):

Arrange the red and green balls first, which can be done in $\ {10\choose 5}\ $ ways. The blue balls can then only be placed one at either end of the row, or in a space between two of the red and green balls.  There are thus exactly 11 places where they can be put, and this can be done in $\ {11\choose 5}\ $ ways.  Therefore, there are $\ {10\choose 5}{11\choose 5}\ $ ways of arranging the balls so that no two blue ones lie next to each other.

Comment: Thanks what i did was 11 choose 5 squared not 10 choose 5 * 11 choose 5. Thank You!